# Specify interface for IPv6 host on link-local connection inside an URL

Tags: browser, lan, ipv6

If using for example Chrome to access a link-local IPv6 host, how can I specify the interface?

The hostname only resolves to a naked IPv6 address as I guess, as with `ping6` for example, I have to add the `-I` option to specify which interface to look for.

So how to place `ping6`'s `-I` option value inside an URL?

Comment: You can't. It doesn't work. Use global or ULA addresses.

Comment: So with IPv6 we now actually have a two-class internet application ecosystem?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: I just mean with IPv6, there are two classes of applications: One that can access certain hosts (link-local connected in this example), while other applications can not access those hosts (eg. some browsers as we see).

Comment: This is a deliberate design choice on the part of the browser makers. There's nothing in IPv6 that would prevent web sites from being served on link-local addresses, but it apparently makes little sense for a modern web browser to access such addresses.

Comment: I run a home network, and many devices offer webacess via local ip4-adresses, like 192.168.0.3 or 192.168.0.6 . I configure my NAS this way and I use MythTV (mythweb) this way. I cannot understand, why webbrowsers cannot connect to ipv6 local.links.

Answer (score 2):

Because every interface uses the same link-local network, an application or OS has no way to unambiguously tell which interface to use, so you must distinguish a link-local address with an interface identifier, or zone. Also, IPv6 addresses in a URI must be surrounded by brackets. For example, `http://[fe80::1234:5678:9abc:def0%9]`. Unfortunately, not all browsers understand the zone ID, which uses the `%`. For those browsers, you cannot use a link-local IPv6 address.